# Nested ajax call in multiple php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have `index.php` which call `url.php` on button click with `ajax` to load without page reload.
Now on 'url.php' there's another button which call `data.php` through ajax.

Right now what happens: When open `index.php` first and click button on `index.php`  it load `url.php` without page load. but when I click button `Fire me` on `url.php` it redirects to `data.php`

If directly I open `url.php` then it performs ajax action and loads  `data.php` without page reload.

What should I make change here so that : When I open first `index.php` and click button on it, it load `url.php` without page reload(this already happens, prblem with next step). After that when I click button on 'url.php' it should load `data.php` without page load.

index.php:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $appId      = '178812862';
    $appSecret  = '390c044f268aca44'; // Facebook App Secret
    $return_url = 'dev01.dev/FB/facebook-php-sdk/examples/'; //path to script folder
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
        <title>ThenWat</title>

        function AjaxResponse()
     {
        //alert("2");
        var mydata;         
        CallAfterLogin(mydata, function(send) {
                   });
      } 
    function LodingAnimate() //Show loading Image
    {
        //alert("animate4");    
      //  $("#LoginButton").hide(); //hide login button once user authorize the application
    }

        </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
                //------------------script 2 starts ---------
                function showUser(form, e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue=false;
                var xmlhttp;
                var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
                xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent);

                return false;
                }

             </script>


    </head>
    <body style="height: 560px">
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    ?>

       <div style="z-index: 1; left: 538px; top: 290px; position: absolute;"> 
        <input class="uibutton confirm large" type="submit" value="Connect with facebook" onclick="AjaxResponse()" > 
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>


    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<?php
    echo $appId;
    ?>',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
    //  channelUrl: '<?php
    echo $return_url;
    ?>channel.php',
        oauth: true});};
    (function() {
            //alert("1");
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());
    function CallAfterLogin(data,callback){
            //alert("CallafterLogin3");
            FB.login(function(response) {  //---
            if (response.status === "connected")
            {
                LodingAnimate(); 
                FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
                console.log(mydata.email);

                //alert("json-5");
                var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
            //    alert(mydata.movies);
                var a = JSON.parse(json);       
                $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a}, function(data) 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                url:'url.php'
                ,async:     true
                ,cache:     false
                ,dataType:  'html'
                ,success:   function(data){
                    $('body').html(data);
                        }
            });        
                });
            console.log(data);

                  }); //--
             } //if
                 }); //---
              } //main function
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

url.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>ThenWat</title>

    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
        </head>
   <body style="height: 560px">
        <form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return showUser(this, event)">
            <div style="z-index: 1; left: 470px; top: 100px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">              
               <label>Enter URL: <input type="text" value="http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html" name="sent" style="width: 400px; height:40px;" ></label><br/>
            </div>
            <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">  <button> Fire me </button>      
            </div>
         </form>
         <div style="z-index: 1; left: 660px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px"> 
            <button onclick="makeAjaxCall(); return false;" value="View Graph" > View Graph </button>
         </div>
    <h3>
         <div id="txtHint" style="z-index: 1; color:green; left: 200px; top: 270px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">       </h3>
         </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}
$textContent = $doc->textContent; //inherited from DOMNode
$text=escapeshellarg($textContent);
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));


//--
    $flag = 0;
    if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Desktop/b '$test'"),  $matches)){ //Values stored in ma. 
    $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
    $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
    $p= (100*$x)/($x+$y);
    $q= (100*$y)/($x+$y);
    echo "<b>Positive count : $x with $p % </b>";  echo "</br>";
    echo "<b>Negative count  : $y with $q % </b>";

    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$flag=0;
// $sql = "INSERT INTO interest (movies,id) VALUES('".$Name."','".$ID."')";
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag) VALUES ('".$x."','".$url."','".$x."','".$y."','".$flag."')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
  // echo "1 record added";
} else {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);



}

?>
```

Bottom line is: creating ajax/jquery system  `index.php -> url.php -> data.php`. 
Existing `index.php -> url.php` and `url.php -> data.php`

Comment: so what is the question or problem?

Comment: @ihsan: What should I make change here so that : When I open first index.php and click button on it, it load url.php without page reload(this already happens, prblem with next step). After that when I click button on 'url.php' it should load data.php without page load.

Comment: Please avoid copying large chunks of code into your files without understanding what they actually do. Half the code you posted here is listed twice and doing nothing.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos: yes you right. I am not very sound with with ajax, jquery. I really could not decide which code do nothing. So I am carrying it with me!

Comment: I will be greateful if you can help me to remove it!

Comment: Can you try to comment out anything in the data.php file and just print a "test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In url.php you have

```
<form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
```

That will definitely cause the form to post. Instead write

```
<form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return showUser(this, event);">
```

And add

```
return false;
```

at the end of the `showUser` function.

EDIT: After various changes in question contents:

I noticed that you are loading the whole url.php into the body of the index.php. Yet, you have `<html>`, `<head>` and `<script>` tags in the url.php which I doubt if they are called. That's why the form just submits itself.

The correct way to go is: Write ALL your Javascript in the index.php file, and just load the new page **contents** by loading the url.php. I was about to write an example, but I saw that you updated your question code, so I hope this cleared things out.

Comment: thanks, but problem till exist. While I click button on `url.php` it load and redirect to `data.php`

Comment: Problem is with `Fire me` button. Please check. It loads `data.php` on click which is the action I have kept in `form`.

Comment: Why don't you update your question code, according to the changes I suggested, also removing the huge parts of unused JS form url.php ? That would help other people understand what you are asking and possibly help another person with the same problem some day in the future.

Comment: but till it does not do what I want!

Comment: Ok got it. I need to place all function code in my first file `index.php`

Comment: thanks for effort. Made my code in question handy, upvote if you like it!

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @mavrosxristoforos

The bottom line is I need to place all the function those being called on buttonclick into first file from which I started the action i.e. `index.php` not in subsequent files `url.php`